# Text overflow from wrapper different browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, overflow

```
HTML

<div class="text-wrapper">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>

CSS

.text-wrapper{
width:100px;
height:45px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

it seems smooth on firefox as two lines but if I open page with chrome or ie9 seems two lines and upper part of the third line.How can I solve this?
Screenshots Firefox - Chrome - IE9

[image: Firefox Screenshot] [image: Chrome Screenshot] [image: ie9 screenshot]

Comment: add font-size to your css. Different browsers have different default values.

Comment: @prestack, please add screenshot if it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have flexible Height use like below:

```
.text-wrapper{
width:100px;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8xXs/1/)

Comment: I don't want flexible height. I want it appears as two lines

Comment: you may need to change `height:44px;` or `height:43px;`, by changing font size it may be difficul.

Answer (score 0):

Add `font-size` to your css. Different browsers have different default values. Also consider using a `CSS reseter` to remove most of the browser differences. [Here's a nice one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I change as 12px improved but broken for 16px again

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding line-height:1 and font-size

Answer (score 0):

you can add line height, greater than your font-size. you can adjust the same as per your requirements

check this code.

```
.text-wrapper{
width:100px;
height:45px;
overflow:hidden;     
float:left;
line-height:15px;         /*Added line height */
border:1px solid #CCC;
}​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jVf95/)